# If input type text is empty, disabled the button type send with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I need a simple code to disable the button to send the form to the following conditions:

If the selected `<input type="radio">` with ID "#radio_one" and then check only one `<input type="text">` with ID "#text_one".

OR

If the selected `<input type="radio">` with ID "# radio_two" and then check two `<input type="text">` with ID "#text_one" and also with ID "#text_two".

And, if provided with one or two `<input type="text">` will be empty, add for a button `<input type="send">` attribute disabled="disabled" if, however, will once again fill this attribute is removed from the button.

Sorry for my English, I used Google Translator: (

I dont have another code, I hope you understand me, so I created some simple jQuery code which can then possibly edit.

Thanks

Edit: This does not work:

```
    $("#send_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");   

    if ($('#absence_one').checked && $('#cal_from').val().length > 0) {
        $("#send_button").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    if ($('#absence_more').checked && $('#cal_to').val().length > 0) {
        $("#send_button").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my example here <s>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8Z7G/)</s>.

I put a `click` listener on the radio to make it check to either disable or undisable the button

I put a `keyup` listener on the text input to make it check to either disable or undisable the button

**EDIT**

I made a slight change to the example here's the new one [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8Z7G/1).

Also be sure you are double checking a submit on the server side.  If someone disables javascript the button will be available for clicking.

```
$("#send_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");   

$("input[type='radio']").change(function()
{
    checkButton();
});

$("input[type='text']").keyup(function()
{
    checkButton();
});

function checkButton()
{
    if (($('#absence_one').is(":checked") && $('#cal_from').val().length > 0) || ($('#absence_more').is(":checked") && $('#cal_to').val().length > 0)) {
        $("#send_button").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#send_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to disable the submit button if either pair of radio button/textbox are unfulfilled. If so:

```
$("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled");   

if ($('#radio_one').checked && $('#text_one').val().length > 0) {
    $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
}

if ($('#radio_two').checked && $('#text_two').val().length > 0) {
    $("input[type=submit]").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Comment: Yes you understand it well, but the code does not work. IDs are correct, but the button is still disabled after entering text.
`$("#send_button").attr("disabled", "disabled");   

  if ($('#absence_one').checked && $('#cal_from').val().length > 0) {
      $("#send_button").removeAttr("disabled");
  }

  if ($('#absence_more').checked && $('#cal_to').val().length > 0) {
      $("#send_button").removeAttr("disabled");
  }`

Comment: try using `.attr("disabled", "true")` instead